# Join two MySQL columns and output colB.name where colA.id is equal to colB.id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'am using CodeIgniter active records and I have a lack in knowledge of Joining multiple table columns in MySQL.

What I basically want to do, is to output all rows from a `ci_categories` table, but instead of showing `ci_categories.component_id` as a numeric, i wish to output the `ci_components.name` which have equal (or same) `ci_components.id` from another table `ci_components` by using the Active Records in CodeIgniter.

What I have already done, but with errors is:

Model:

```
public function getItemName($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    $result = $query->result();

    return $result;
}
```

and View:

```
<?php echo $this->component_model->getItemName($cat['category']->com_id);?>
```

Any tips pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('name')
->from('ci_components')
->where('ci_categories.component_id = ci_componenents.id');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

or

```
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->from('ci_components');
$this->db->join('ci_categories', 'categories.component_id = ci_components.id');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: And where I should put this code, in which model ? Into `categories_model` or into `component_model` ?

Comment: I'd probably go with components since we are trying to retrieve the name of components.